# vagrantのターミナルでcdを使用し、ファイルを開こうとしても開くことができません。

Tags: php

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]プログラミング初心者です。vagrantのターミナルでcd php_lessons のコマンドを使用し、php_lessons の『フォルダ』(ファイルではありません)を開こうとしても開くことができません。『No such file or directory』と、出ます。他のvagrant up , cd MyCentOSなどのコマンドは作動したのですが。。詳しい方教えていただけると幸いです。。

Comment: `cd`は一般的に「ディレクトリ(フォルダ)を移動する」コマンドですがお間違えないでしょうか。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！もしエラーメッセージなど出ていた場合、質問文に追記することで回答が得られやすくなる可能性があります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます(T . T)

Comment: `No such file or directory` と表示されているのでしたら、その場所(カレントディレクトリ)には `php_lessons` というディレクトリがないという事なのでしょう。`pwd` コマンドを実行すると、カレントディレクトリのパス名を表示してくれますし、`ls -la` を実行すればカレントディレクトリにあるファイルやディレクトリを表示してくれます。一度、確認してみる事をお勧めします。

Comment: ありがとうございます！一度確認してみます！！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linuxでは、ファイルの中身を見たい場合は、viやtailをお使いください。

cd <パス>
現在のディレクトリを移動

vi <パス>
ファイルをテキストエディタ(vi)で開く

tail -n 100 <パス>
ファイルの下100行を表示